# Suma y resta en formularios con modelos en Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Yo tengo un moedo y me gustaria saber como pueod hacer una operacion en un formulario, que se sume o se agregue automaticamente a la hora de adicionar valores numericos, en unos ejemplos he visto que lo hacen desde el archivo de modelo, otros desde el forms.py, pero no entiendo muy bien.

```
models.py
class UserProfile(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
consecutivo = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
usuario = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
nombre = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null=True, blank=True)
apellido = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null=True, blank=True)
numero_empleado = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
area = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null=True, blank=True)
F_nac = models.DateField(max_length = 200, null=True, blank=True)
D_pendientes = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
H_pendientes = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
F_init = models.DateField(max_length = 200, null=True, blank=True)
Init_vac = models.DateField(max_length = 200, null=True, blank=True)
Fin_vac = models.DateField(max_length = 200, null=True, blank=True)
ul_vac_tomadas = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True, null=True, blank=True)
is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=True)

USERNAME_FIELD = 'usuario'

forms.py
class SolitForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = UserProfile
    fields = ['D_pendientes','H_pendientes','Init_vac',
        'Fin_vac',
        'ul_vac_tomadas',]

    labels = { 
        'D_pendientes':'Dias disposnibles',
        'H_pendientes':'Horas disponibles',
        'Init_vac':'Inicio de Vacaciones',
        'Fin_vac':'Fin de vacaciones',
        'ul_vac_tomadas':'Ultimas vacaciones',
    }
    widgets = {
        'D_pendientes': forms.NumberInput(),
        'H_pendientes': forms.NumberInput(),
        'Init_vac': forms.DateInput(),
        'Fin_vac': forms.DateInput(),
        'ul_vac_tomadas': forms.NumberInput(),

    }
```

Si yo quiero sumar o restar el valor que ingrese el usuario vs lo que hay en la base de datos como seria? Los valores de tienen el tipo correo del campo "IntegerFields". gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vaya cacao tienes amigo, es la segunda vez que veo esta pregunta.

El modelo lo tienes incorrecto, los atributos `usuario`, `nombre`, `apellido`, `is_active` y `is_staff` están duplicados, pues los estás heredando de `AbstractUser`, no necesitas volver a ponerlos. `consecutivo` también te sobra, pues por defecto ya tienes una clave primaria denominada `id`.

Para el caso de `usuario` heredas `username`, `nombre` = `first_name`, `apellido` = `last_name`, los restantes mencionados son iguales.

Para sumar dos valores tal y como quieres hacer sería conveniente que lo hicieras en el `views.py`:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        solitForm = SolitForm(data=request.POST)
        if solitForm.is_valid():
            # Obtienes el objeto que dices que quieres adicionar
            s = SolitForm.objects.get(pk=5)
            s.ul_vac_tomadas += solitForm.cleaned_data.get('ul_vac_tomadas')
            s.save()
            return HttpResponse('')
```

Comment: Que significa la variable "s", para ti?, porque pk=5? Ayuda por favor